# SharePoint 2013 crawler can't crawl unrelated SharePoint web app on unrelated farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-search

Playing with our test 2013 SharePoint server.   Trying to tell the search crawler to index a site on a different farm's web app, but the crawled site is responding with an Access Denied.   In the crawling server, I set the site to be crawled as a web site, not a SharePoint site.

I believe the crawled web app can see that a Sharepoint crawler is coming in, and is treating it as the local farm...so it's trying to treat it like the local SharePoint farm search engine...which it's not.

I don't want to add one farm's permissions to the second... I just want things to respond as if any dumb crawler were coming to the door.

the target box is open to all user-agents, and allows anonymous access.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your crawl account(Content Access Account) should have the read permission to that web app.

Did you set that permission.

For anonymous web application, follow this link.

http://www.sharepoint24x7.com/2014/07/09/article-anonymous-crawl-configuration-in-sharepoint-2013/